# How can i validate more than one email address?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea where user can enter multiple email address. So is there any way to validate them all.

Currently I am using ng-pattern to vaalidate it.

Comment: Split them using `\n` and then test each of them...

Comment: What have you done already? Can you provide relevant code?

Comment: It's very simple. Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233686/validate-multiple-email-addresses-in-single-field/37877265#37877265

Comment: i am using ng-pattern in which i provided a email pattern to validate it.

Comment: Thanks @surjeet, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found this one and did the job for me

```
.directive('multipleEmails', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {

        var emails = viewValue.split(',');
        // loop that checks every email, returns undefined if one of them fails.
        var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

        // angular.foreach(emails, function() {
          var validityArr = emails.map(function(str){
              return re.test(str.trim());
          }); // sample return is [true, true, true, false, false, false]
          console.log(emails, validityArr); 
          var atLeastOneInvalid = false;
          angular.forEach(validityArr, function(value) {
            if(value === false)
              atLeastOneInvalid = true; 
          }); 
          if(!atLeastOneInvalid) { 
            // ^ all I need is to call the angular email checker here, I think.
            ctrl.$setValidity('multipleEmails', true);
            return viewValue;
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('multipleEmails', false);
            return undefined;
          }
        // })
      });
    }
  };
});
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233686/validate-multiple-email-addresses-in-single-field)