# Validate phone number using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-validation

Want to set phone-number to **10** digits, How can I do this using Angular js.

This is what I have tried:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="registration" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': registration.phone.$error.number}">
    <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="number" 
             class="form-control" 
             ng-minlength="10" 
             ng-maxlength="10"  
             id="inputPhone" 
             name="phone" 
             placeholder="Phone" 
             ng-model="user.phone" 
             ng-required="true">
      <span class="help-block" 
            ng-show="registration.phone.$error.required && 
                     registration.phone.$error.number">
                     Valid phone number is required
      </span>
      <span class="help-block" 
            ng-show="((registration.password.$error.minlength || 
                      registration.password.$error.maxlength) && 
                      registration.phone.$dirty) ">
                      phone number should be 10 digits
       </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But I am not getting the validation error.

Comment: what about international phone numbers?

Comment: Your `ng-show`s are looking for `registration.phone` but the `ng-model` of your input is `user.phone`

Comment: registration is form name I am using that one.. @rwacarter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="registration" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': registration.phone.$error.number}">
        <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="number" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   ng-minlength="10" 
                   ng-maxlength="10"  
                   id="inputPhone" 
                   name="phone" 
                   placeholder="Phone" 
                   ng-model="user.phone"
                   ng-required="true">
            <span class="help-block" 
                  ng-show="registration.phone.$error.required || 
                           registration.phone.$error.number">
                           Valid phone number is required
            </span>
            <span class="help-block" 
                  ng-show="((registration.phone.$error.minlength ||
                           registration.phone.$error.maxlength) && 
                           registration.phone.$dirty) ">
                           phone number should be 10 digits
            </span>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is browser specific, but in Chrome, this input will currently show with a tiny incrementer/decrementer at the end of the input. It has little arrows to increase and decrease the number.

Comment: input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: keep in mind if the number starts with 0 zero, the zero will be eliminated.

Answer (score 8):

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900308/angularjs-dynamic-ng-pattern-validation)

Basically you can create a regex to fulfil your needs and then assign that pattern to your input field.

Or for a more direct approach:

```
<input type="number" require ng-pattern="<your regex here>">
```

More info @ angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) and [here (built-in validators)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use ng-pattern ,[7-9] = > mobile number must start with 7 or 8 or 9 ,[0-9] = mobile number accepts digits ,{9} mobile number should be 10 digits.

```js
function form($scope){
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="form">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="number" ng-model="mobile_number" name="mobile_number" ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.mobile_number.$error.pattern">Please enter valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not seem to be a very international rule... maybe you can tell for which country this is valid.

Comment: ok I agree with you.I wrote this code for Indian country mobile numbers validation.Thank you.

Comment: what is the use of `ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/"` then how to use same method in email validation?..

Comment: ng-pattern used to write our own regular expression,for email validation you can use this **[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}**.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ng-pattern` and I feel that will be a best practice. Similarly try to use `ng-message`. Please look the ng-pattern attribute on the following html. The code snippet is partial but hope you understand it.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
angular.module("myApp.controllers",[]).controller("registerCtrl", function($scope, Client) {
  $scope.ph_numbr = /^(\+?(\d{1}|\d{2}|\d{3})[- ]?)?\d{3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/;
});
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="registration" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (registration.phone.$invalid || registration.phone.$pristine)}">
    <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-pattern="ph_numbr"  id="inputPhone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="user.phone" ng-required="true">
      <div class="help-block" ng-messages="registration.phone.$error">
        <p ng-message="required">Phone number is required.</p>
        <p ng-message="pattern">Phone number is invalid.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

use ng-intl-tel-input to validate mobile numbers for all countries. you can set default country also.
on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-intl-tel-input

more details: https://techpituwa.wordpress.com/2017/03/29/angular-js-phone-number-validation-with-ng-intl-tel-input/

Comment: This library works perfectly, the only downside is that it requires jquery.

Answer (score 1):

An even cleaner and more professional look I have found is to use AngularUI Mask. Very simple to implement and the mask can be customized for other inputs as well. Then a simple required validation is all you need.

https://angular-ui.github.io/

Comment: The UI-Mask is awesome, except... It has this nasty functionality where if the pattern match fails, it clears the field on focus-away.

Comment: @PKD, you can add `ui-options="{clearOnBlur: false}"` to disable that behavior, at least on the most recent versions of angular-ui-mask.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name = "numberForm">
    <div>
    <input type="number"
           placeholder = "Enter your phonenumber"
           class = "formcontroll"
           name = "numbers"
           ng-minlength = "10"
           ng-maxlength = "10"
           ng-model="phno" required/>
           <p ng-show = "numberForm.numbers.$error.required ||
                       numberForm.numbers.$error.number">
                       Valid phone number is required</p>
            <p ng-show = "((numberForm.numbers.$error.minlength ||
                        numberForm.numbers.$error.maxlength)
                        && numberForm.numbers.$dirty)">
                        Phone number should be 10 digits</p><br><br>
       </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-pattern, in this example you can validate a simple patern with 10 numbers, when the patern is not matched ,the message is show and the button is disabled.

```
 <form  name="phoneNumber">

        <label for="numCell" class="text-strong">Phone number</label>

        <input id="numCell" type="text" name="inputCelular"  ng-model="phoneNumber" 
            class="form-control" required  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,10}$/"></input>
        <div class="alert-warning" ng-show="phoneNumber.inputCelular.$error.pattern">
            <p> write a phone number</p>
        </div>

    <button id="button"  class="btn btn-success" click-once ng-disabled="!phoneNumber.$valid" ng-click="callDigitaliza()">Buscar</button>
```

Also you can use another complex patern like

^+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?(?(?:\d{2,3}))?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$

, for more complex phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.mobileno.$error.pattern ,'has-success': userForm.mobileno.$valid}">

              <input type="text" name="mobileno" ng-model="mobileno" ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/"  required>
```

Here "userForm" is my form name.