# Phone number verification in html

Tags: angularjs, html

I have html code and it checks phone number keyed in is whether valid or not.
I can't find how it check to validate the phone number.

The problem is it's validation doesn't allow + sign and start with 0.
How can I allow + sign and start with 0 at phone number validation.

My html code is as follow.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : consumerRegisterForm.Office_no.$invalid && (consumerRegisterForm.Office_no.$dirty || submitted)}">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="icon fa fa-phone-square"></i>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="RegisterData.Office_no" name="Office_no" placeholder="Office Phone Number" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <p class="validation-error" ng-show="consumerRegisterForm.Office_no.$error.required && (consumerRegisterForm.Office_no.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Please Enter office phone number.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your phone number validated ?

Comment: I can't find in my source code. It should have? But why I can't find the validation source.

Comment: Yes, these validations are usually made in javascript. What framework do you use ?

Comment: it is in  AngularJS. What key word should I use to search? invalid and dirty? I used invalid and dirty, I can't find validation in controller js code.

Comment: You can use `ng-pattern` to validate. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986173/validate-phone-number-using-angular-js

Comment: You could change the input type from `number` to `tel`. This way it gets validated as a phone number.

Comment: @chillichief so I can start with 0 and can include +? let me try. thanks

Comment: @chillichief yes it worked.

Comment: Just to clarify: The input does not get validated by javaScript, but by the browser itself. check http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url so see which browser supports this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is `type="number"`. It means it only allows... numbers.

As you want to use `+` and leading zeros, you may want to change it to `text`:

```
<input type="text" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input type "text" and make directive which will fulfill your requirements