# angular form validation for specific values

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that needs to validate for specific first name.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info.first_name" ng-pattern="/\bJane\b/">
```

The issue is that the first name "Jane" needs to be set in the controller.

Is it possible to dynamically set this using ng-pattern?

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jx9PRBce72lh4tPrMZ5Q?p=preview)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18984874/13468, there are two ways shown to do this.

Comment: @mlibby I saw that question but I'd rather not use a directive and don't believe it's possible to create a regex with a string while not making the regex a string. I've added a plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define the regex as a scope variable:

```
 $scope.pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + $scope.second_name + '\\b');

 <input type="text" ng-model="first_name" ng-pattern="pattern" required>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fsAILhdutlSf3ztcgZDA

Answer (score 0):

You can see the full [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6lWuSB5cpfJJVjQnFuOf?p=preview) I made from yours, but the relevant bit is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984874/13468

```
$scope.getPattern = (function() {
    var regexp = function() {return new RegExp('\\b'+ $scope.second_name +'\\b')};
    return {
      test: function (value) {
        return regexp().test(value);
      }
    }
  })();
```

I used a function for the internal `regexp` because I want to wait until the pattern is actually tested to get the value of `$scope.second_name` to include in the RegExp.