# Regular expression for numbers in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want to use regular expression in AngularJs that accept this three statement :

```
09344542525 -> 11 length integer that start with 09

02144532363 -> 11 length integer that start with 021

44532363 -> 8 length integer
```

Here is my **HTML** :

```
<div class="container co-operate" ng-controller="cooperationController">
    <form novalidate name="cooperationForm" class="signinform">
        <div class="form-group inner-addon right-inner-addon">
            <label class="form-label control-label"></label>
            <input ng-model="restaurantInformation.tel" type="text" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="phone number"
               ng-pattern="mobRegEx || prePhoneRegEx || phoneRegEx" class="form-control default-input singleline-input" required />
            <span class="form-icon icon icon-avatar"></span>
        </div>
        <p ng-show="cooperationForm.tel.$error.pattern" style="color: red">Wrong number format</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Angular:**

```
app.controller('cooperationController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.mobRegEx = '/09[0-3][0-9]{8}/';
    $scope.prePhoneRegEx = '/021[0-9]{8}/';
    $scope.phoneRegEx = '[0-9]{8}';
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Actually , when my input is dirty and I test integer, error paragraph is always show error.

Any suggestion to modify regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 3 combined:

```
/^(?:0(?:21|9[0-9]))?[0-9]{8}$/
```

**Description**

- `^` matches the beginning of string
- `(?:`..`)?` is an optional group matching

  - `0(?:21|9[0-9])` literal `021` OR...
  - `09` and another digit
- `[0-9]{8}` 8 more digits
- `$` matching the end of string as well.

---

Notice I added [`^` and `$` anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to avoid matching a substring

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use multiple regular expressions in `ng-pattern` by separating them using pipes - that's not valid. As suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438353/how-to-apply-multiple-ng-pattern-with-one-input-control) you should implement a custom directive (`ng-phone-number`?) or combine your multiple expressions into a single pattern.

Using a directive will probably be the most maintainable approach.

Comment: I've completed my question.

Comment: My answer still stands; implement a custom directive that tests the inputs against any of the regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

> var regExp = /(+09|021|44532363)\d{1,12}/g;
>   var result = string.match(regExp); 
>   console.log(result)