# Conditional ng-pattern in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

Is there a way to achieve conditional ng-pattern in angularjs

```
ng-pattern="(myForm.exipration.$dirty ? ('/^\d{2}[/]\d{4}$/') : '')"
```

i tried like above, but does not help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Markup

```html
<input ... ng-pattern="handlePatternPassword">
```

#### Controller

```js
$scope.handlePatternPassword = (function() {
  var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{4,20}$/;
  return {
    test: function(value) {
      if ($scope.user.isLogged) {
        return (value.length > 0) ? regex.test(value) : true;
      } else {
        return regex.test(value);
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984874/4640499.

Comment: @ Jonatas Walker - worked perfectly. How does it work?

Comment: Inside `test` function make your conditionals. Return a `boolean` for your validation.

Comment: i dont wanna make function i wanna do this in html but it is not working can you provide answer for using this in html

Answer (score 11):

The following worked for me (AngularJS v1.5.11):

```
ng-pattern="condition ? '[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,60}' : ''"
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle for this? I can't get it to work with this version of AngularJS. here is an example to set a pattern for multiple of 25 http://jsfiddle.net/9bua4k2d/1/

Comment: this doesnt seem to work with the latest version on Angular 7/8  `patterm="condition ? '[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,60}' : ''` Do you know of any good solutions