# Conditional ng-pattern angularjs 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-pattern

I would like to apply an ng-pattern validation on my input

```
<div ng-if="item.usage.dataType == 'integer' || item.usage.dataType == 'date'" ng-init="filter[item.ids]['dataType'] = item.usage.dataType">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filter.[item.ids]['value']" />
</div>
```

But I only want to validate the input if `item.usage.dataType == 'date'`

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832062/conditional-ng-pattern-in-angular-js) but I have no way to know what is the dataType with this.

How can I make a conditional validation without repeating the DOM?

Thanks

Comment: Could this help? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832062/conditional-ng-pattern-in-angular-js.

Comment: That's the link I've provided in my question :)