# Adding custom validation to angular textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I want to add custom validation to the angular form.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputAmount.$invalid && submitted }">
    <label for="inputAmount" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Amount</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         <textarea ng-model="formData.inputAmount" class="validate[required,custom[comment]] feedback-input" rows="4" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Enter Amount to Convert" required></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want only number or decimal input with inverted commas like

```
"1"
"123.1"
"123.12221"
```

How can i add this pattern

Help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: something like `/^[0-9]+((\.)?[0-9]+)?$/`   ?

Comment: where to add this pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Directive for custom validations.

First write custom directive:

```
//Check For FLoat Validation
 adminApp.directive('validateFloat', function() {
 var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+((\.)\d+)?$/;

return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: '',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        // only apply the validator if ngModel is present and Angular has added the Float Number validator
        ctrl.$validators.validateFloat = function(modelValue) {
            return  ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || FLOAT_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
        };

    }
};
});
```

In directive used **Regex** for float (or) Decimal to check with **ngModel** value.

Then use directive in html page.

```
<input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" ng-model=test.amount" validate-float required>
                                <span class="error-container" ng-show="myForm.amount.$dirty && myForm.amount.$invalid">
                            <span ng-cloak style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.amount.$error.required">Please Enter amount</span>
                            <span ng-cloak style="color:red" ng-show="!myForm.amount.$error.required&&myForm.amount.$error.validateFloat">Enter valid amount</span>
                          </span>
```

In HTML page mention the custom directive **"validate-float"** as attribute. And for showing error message in **ng-Show** mention the **$error.validateFloat**.

For more info about directive and validations: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive,
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-pattern to validate your textarea.

Checkout here for example.
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/AngularJS/AngularJS_Example/Directives/Use_ng_pattern_to_validate.htm

Refer here for dynamic ng-pattern validation [Angularjs dynamic ng-pattern validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900308/angularjs-dynamic-ng-pattern-validation)