# Store Multiple Validators into a Constant in Angular 8 Reactive FormBuilders

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

How do I store Multiple Validators into a Constant and use in Reactive FormBuilder?
The following will apply 1 validator.
[Store and Use Regex Const Validator in Angular 8 Reactive Formbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464574/store-and-use-regex-const-validator-in-angular-8-reactive-formbuilder/59464727?noredirect=1#comment105110359_59464727)

```
export const ZipValidation = Validators.pattern(/^\d{1,5}$/);

'ZipCode': [null, [Validators.maxLength(16), ZipValidation]],
```

We need to store a whole multiple array into a constant.
This is multiple validators for latitude and longitude.

```
Validators.maxLength(32),
Validators.min(-90),
Validators.max(90),
Validators.pattern(/^\d*\.?\d*$/)
```

I tried doing the following, it is not working

```
export const LatitudeLongitudeValidator = [Validators.maxLength(32),Validators.min(-90),Validators.max(90),Validators.pattern(/^\d*\.?\d*$/)];

'latitude': [null, [LatitudeLongitudeValidator]],
```

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have array of all these validations and then using spread operator use that array inside validator,

```js
export const CustomValidation = [
    Validators.maxLength(32),
    Validators.min(-90),
    Validators.max(90),
    Validators.pattern(/^\d*\.?\d*$/)
]
```

Use this array in formgroup,

```js
'formField': ['', [ ...CustomValidation ]],
```

Spread operator is 3 periods dots `...` just before array variable.

Comment: you need to use spread operator `...`, do it like this `'latitude': [null, [...LatitudeLongitudeValidator]],`