# NgMask force custom pattern

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have an AngularJS project where I am using [NgMask](http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/) plugin, I want to force users to enter a specific pattern inside an input box.

Pattern example goes like: **X**01**Y**1234**Z**55

Where X,Y and Z are static characters, and users shouldn't be able to enter any other characters other than them, and the digits count should remain the same, X .. 2 Digits .. Y .. 4 Digits .. Z .. 2 Digits.

I have tried to use:

`<input type="text" ng-model="unique_id" mask="X99Y9999Z99" restrict="reject">`

but unfortunately that didn't work.

I am not familiar with Regex complicated stuff, so I am hoping that some Regex experts can help us out with that.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to roll out your own regex. The NgMask has no way to redefine the [masks](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/blob/master/src/services/maskService.js#L16).

Comment: I think I can add the mask to the script if I knew what is it. No?

Comment: It is a basic regex that you can learn in half an hour at http://regexone.com. `^X\d{2}Y\d{4}Z\d{2}$` or `^X[0-9]{2}Y[0-9]{4}Z[0-9]{2}$`. See https://regex101.com/r/wZdVhs/1. It is a regular expression, but ngMask does not accept regex as a mask, you need to implement the regex check yourself in the ng model using `pattern` (or `ng-pattern`) attribute. If you share the code we could help more.

Comment: Thank you. My project is really big and I cannot separate it to show an example, but ngMask already provides example [here](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/tree/master/examples). I added your pattern to the `patterns` object in the ngMask script and gave it a random name to test, unfortunately non of the ones you shared worked, with `restrict="reject"` (which i really need) your patterns prevented me from inserting anything.

Comment: I told you ngMask does not accept regex, why even try to put it there? Implement the regex validation using Angular. There are plenty of resources here and in the Web.

Comment: Sorry Wiktor I apologize, I might be got you wrong. I can do it using `ng-pattern` but then that will not prevent the user from inserting wrong pattern data, it just doesn't validate the value. I'll give it a check, thank you so much for the time!

Comment: I know. There are other ways, like using the regex with the ng model that will validate live. I remember this question but cannot find it now. If I find I will share.

Comment: Would using this directive be a good approach to do it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984874/2654691

Comment: Yes, using the directive is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pattern` attribute of `input` as  below.

```
<input pattern="X[0-9]{2}Y[0-9]{4}Z【0-9】{2}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that did not work with my case using ngMask. Even `ng-pattern` , your pattern might be correct but it didn't work with my case.